# Inject OSGi Services in a non-component class

Tags: dependency-injection, osgi

Usually I have seen in OSGi development that one service binds to another service. However I am trying to inject an OSGi service in a non-service class.

Scenario trying to achieve: I have implemented a MessageBusListener which is an OSGi service and binds to couple of more services like QueueExecutor etc.

Now one of the tasks of the MessageBusListener is to create a FlowListener (non-service class) which would invoke the flows based on the message content. This FlowListener requires OSGi services like QueueExecutor to invoke the flow.

One of the approach I tried was to pass the reference of the services while creating the instance of FlowListener from MessageBusListener. However when the parameterized services are deactivated and activated back, I think OSGi service would create a new instance of a service and bind to MessageBusListener, but FlowListener would still have a stale reference.

```
@Component
public class MessageBusListener
{
    private final AtomicReference<QueueExecutor> queueExecutor = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Activate
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> osgiMap)
    {
        FlowListener f1 = new FlowListener(queueExeciutor)
    }

    Reference (service = QueueExecutor.class, cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY, policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    protected void bindQueueExecutor(QueueExecutor queueExecutor)
    {
        this.queueExecutor = queueExecutor;
    }
}

public class FlowListener
{
    private final AtomicReference<QueueExecutor> queueExecutor;

    FlowListener(QueueExecutor queueExecutor)
    {
        this.queueExecutor = queueExecutor;
    }
    queueExecutor.doSomething() *// This would fail in case the QueueExecutor 
    service was deactivated and activated again*
}
```

Looking forward to other approaches which could suffice my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct you just need to also handle the deactivation if necessary.

If the QueueExecutor disappears the MessageBuslistener will be shut down. You can handle this using a @Deactivate method. In this method you can then also call a sutdown method of FlowListener.

If a new QeueExecutor service comes up then DS will create a new MessageBuslistener so all should be fine.

Btw. you can simply inject the QueueExecutor using:

```
@Reference
QueueExecutor queueExecutor;
```

Comment: Yes, i thought of this approach as well. Like MessageBusListener can keep track of all the created FlowListeners and upon deactivation, it can destroy the existing FlowListeners. However, creating and destroying would be a more computation process. I wanted to expose if OSGi provides capability to handle this scenario

Comment: Ah .. so there are several QueueExecutor services and you want one FlowListener for each of these?

Comment: No. There would be an OSGi defined property called Queues (would come along osgiMap during activate/modify of MessageBusListener). This property would be comma separated, providing queue address. So for each queue address, there would be a new dedicated FlowListener.

Comment: I think in this case I would manage a map of FlowListener instances in MessageBuslistener.